# Deserialize json based on an enum in the json

Tags: json, struct, rust, serde

Is it possible to use a value in JSON to determine how to deserialize the rest of the JSON using serde? For example, consider the following code:

```
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};
use serde_repr::*;

#[derive(Serialize_repr, Deserialize_repr, Debug)]
#[repr(u8)]
enum StructType {
    Foo = 1,
    Bar = 2
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Foo {
    a: String,
    b: u8
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Bar {
    x: String,
    y: u32,
    z: u16
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct AllMyStuff {
    type: StructType,
    data: //HELP: Not sure what to put here
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is deserialization of the data, even if in multiple steps, where the `type` field in the `AllMyStuff` determines which type of struct data is present in `data`. For example, given the following pseudocode, I'd like to ultimately have a `Bar` struct with the proper data in it:

```
data = {"type": "2", "data": { "x": "Hello world", "y": "18", "z": "5" } }
// 1) use serde_json to deserialize a AllMyStuff struct, not erroring on the "data" blob
// 2) Now that we know data is of type "2" (or Bar), parse the remaining "data" into a AllMyStuff struct
```

If steps (1) and (2) are somehow able to be done in a single step, that would be awesome but not needed. I'm not sure what type of type to declare `data` in the `AllMyStuff` struct to enable this as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`serde_json::Value`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/enum.Value.html) as the type for `AllMyStuff::data`. It will deserialize *any* valid json object and also implements `Deserialize` itself, so it can be further deserialized once the type to deserialize to is known (via `AllMyStuff::type`). While this requires more intermittent steps and (mostly temporary) types, it saves you from manually implementing `Deserialize` on an `enum AllMyStuff { Foo(Foo), Bar(Bar) }`.

Comment: Ah thank you, this is very helpful. I didn't know the `enum AllMyStuff { Foo(Foo), Bar(Bar) }` was possible, and it's very insightful to know that. Your use of `serde_json::Value` is ultimately the route I was wanting to go and got me where I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something, but `AllMyStuff` looks as if you are trying to manually distinguish between `Foo` and `Bar`.

However, Rust, has a *built-in* way of doing this:

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
enum AllMyStuff {
    Foo(Foo),
    Bar(Bar),
}
```

Click [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=027debf326d8648ab4fca99cc6a90beb) to see it in action.